# For each form keyup

Tags: jquery

I have multiple forms on one page and i want to disable their submit buttons until they are filled.

It looks like this:

```js
$('form input').keyup(function() {

  var empty = false;
  $('form input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      empty = true;
    }
  });

  if (empty) {
    $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
    $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="user_input" name="username" placeholder="name" /><br />
  <input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="user_input" name="username" placeholder="name" /><br />
  <input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

I tried to wrap everything with $("form").each(function() so that each form is separate but it does not work. My english is not great and i really am a jquery newbie so any help would be appreciated.
http://jsfiddle.net/qKG5F/3200/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you must note that the `id` attribute should be unique. So instead of give an the same `id` to multiple html tags you must use the `class` attribute I did below:

```
id="user_input"
```

should be

```
class="user_input"
```

After that when you use the selector `$('form input')` you are not selecting the form/inputs related to the `input` that fire the `keyup` events. So you must reach the parent related to this input as a first step, then target all the children inputs, like this:

```
$(this).parent().find("input")
```

Same thing with the register input:

```
 $(this).parent().find('.register')
```

Finally here is a DEMO:

```js
$('form input').keyup(function() {

    var empty = false;
    $(this).parent().find("input").each(function() {
  
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $(this).parent().find('.register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
         $(this).parent().find('.register').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="text" class="user_input" name="username" placeholder="name" /><br /> 
    <input type="submit" class="register" value="Register" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
<form>
    <input type="text" class="user_input" name="username" placeholder="name" /><br /> 
    <input type="submit" class="register" value="Register" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

Comment: great, works like a charm! but, if the input field is wrapped in div (bootstrap's markup), then it does not work... http://jsfiddle.net/qKG5F/3203/

Comment: my bad, found a way :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be considering `keyup` `change` `keypress` `blur` events to enable/disable the button:

```js
required = function(fields) {
  console.clear();
  var valid = true;
  fields.each(function() { // iterate all
    var $this = $(this);
    if ((($this.is(':text') || $this.is('textarea')) && !$this.val())) {
      valid = false;
    }
  });
  return valid;
}

validateRealTime = function() {
  var fields = $("form :input");
  fields.on('keyup change keypress blur', function() {
    if (required(fields)) {
      {
        $("#register").prop('disabled', false);
      }
    } else {
      {
        $("#register").prop('disabled', true);
      }
    }
  });
}

validateRealTime();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  First name<br />
  <input type="text" id="user_input" name="firstname" /><br /> Name
  <br />
  <input type="name" id="name_input" name="name" /><br /> Email<br />
  <input type="email" id="email_input" name="email" /><br />
  <br/> Your Message
  <textarea name="your_message" id="your_message"></textarea>
  <br>

  <input type="submit" id="register" value="Submit" disabled="disabled" />

</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

the problem is that you are using same id for two buttons. try changing the id or make the id to class

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="user_input_1" name="username" placeholder="name" /><br /> 
<input type="submit" id="register_1" value="Register" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
<form>
<input type="text" id="user_input_2" name="username" placeholder="name" /><br /> 
<input type="submit" id="register_2" value="Register" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
(function() {
$('#user_input_1').keyup(function() {
    var empty = false;
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    if (empty) {
        $('#register_1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#register_1').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
 $('#user_input_2').keyup(function() {
    var empty = false;
              if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    if (empty) {
        $('#register_2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#register_2').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
})()
```

Comment: thanks for the help but that is not it :/ try adding anything in first input, button bellow should be enabled. http://jsfiddle.net/qKG5F/3201/